# how to return one column based on a condition depending on a different column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to add new column to a DataFrame based on a condition.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'category' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
               'value': [10,10,20,20]
                   })
```

On DataFrame above, I would like to add separated columns ['Value A'], ['Value B'], ['Value C'] to make calculations easier. Desired output would be like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'category' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
               'value': [10,10,20,20]
               'Value A' : [10, 10, 0, 0]
               'Value B' : [0, 0, 20, 0]
               'Value C' : [0, 0, 0, 20]
                   })
```

I thought I could just do it by

```
df['Value A'] = df['value'](add some condition here).fillna(0)
```

But seems like it can be done this simple. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df.join(df.reset_index()
   .pivot_table(index='index', columns='category', 
                values='value', fill_value=0)
   .reindex(['A','B','C'], axis=1, fill_value=0)         # from comment
   .add_prefix('value')
)
```

Output:

```
  category  value  valueA  valueB  valueC
0        A     10      10       0       0
1        A     10      10       0       0
2        B     20       0      20       0
3        C     20       0       0      20
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer!
Do you think it is possible to add ValueX column even when the categoryX doesnt appear in the 'category' column?
I mean, category A, B and C dont always appear in the column so for ex, when C doesnt appear in the category, I would still like to have 'ValueC' column filled with 0.
I know A, B and C is the all categories could appear tho.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary pairing the new column names with the conditions:

```
condition = {f"Value {letter}": df.loc[df.category.eq(letter), "value"]
             for letter in df.category.unique()}

condition

{'Value A': 0    10
 1    10
 Name: value, dtype: int64,
 'Value B': 2    20
 Name: value, dtype: int64,
 'Value C': 3    20
 Name: value, dtype: int64}
```

**Update**: Lovely suggestion from @QuangHoang - you can build the `condition` dictionary with a groupby :

```
 condition = {f"Value {k}": d for k, d in df.groupby("category")["value"]}
```

Now unpack the `condition` via [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df.assign(**condition).fillna(0)

    category    value   Value A Value B Value C
0      A          10    10.0     0.0    0.0
1      A          10    10.0     0.0    0.0
2      B          20    0.0     20.0    0.0
3      C          20    0.0      0.0    20.0
```

Comment: `condition = {f'Value {k}': d for k,d in df.groupby('category')['value']}`?

Comment: Nice. I'll add it as an alternative.